# Format an ISODate form field in ReactiveMongo Play JSON

Tags: json, mongodb, scala, playframework

Using MongoDB with Play Framework and the [ReactiveMongo Play JSON library](http://reactivemongo.org/releases/0.12/documentation/json/overview.html); I am trying to correctly configure a *form*. I have some dates stored in MongoDB which are in an `ISODate` wrapper/monad and handled as a `JSObject`:

```
   Json.obj("dateOfBirth" -> Json.obj("$date" -> dateTimeLong))
```

An example of my case class using [automated mapping in Play](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ScalaJsonAutomated) is:

```
   case class FormData(_id: Option[BSONObjectID], name: String, dateOfBirth: Option[JSObject])
```

This is the form:

```
  object MyForm {

     val form = Form(
        mapping(
          "_id" -> ignored(Option.empty[BSONObjectID]),
          "name" -> nonEmptyText,
          "dateofBirth" -> ? // not `date` or `optional(date)`
        )
     )

  }
```

I think that I need to custom bind the `dateOfBirth` field in the `form` but this is where I am having difficulty. I couldn't find where to include an implicit object to format a new type as [shown here](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ScalaForms#custom-binders-for-form-mappings) and [this](http://www.ethanjoachimeldridge.info/tech-blog/how-custom-type-form-binders-for-playframework) also didn't help me with this (and looks like it might be outdated by now).

I think that the `bind` method might look something like this:

```
  def bind(date: Date, dateFieldName: String): JsObject = {

    val longDate = new DateTime(date.getTime())
      .withZoneRetainFields(DateTimeZone.UTC)
      .withZone(DateTimeZone.getDefault())
      .getMillis

    Json.obj(s"$$$dateFieldName" -> JsNumber(longDate))

  }
```

But I could be wrong and it would be nice to try however as I say I can't seem to find where the correct place to insert a `custom formatter` - I thought this should be in the *companion object* of `FormData` (where formats would be for nested fields). This wasn't the case so I am approaching the community once more. Thanks for any suggestions - particularly if there is a better way to handle this.

Comment: Seriously - has no one got anything on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I knew that the answer was out there but it definitely shouldn't have been so well hidden! This one is for anyone that is feeling my pain. So I changed the following:

```
   case class FormData(_id: Option[BSONObjectID], name: String, dateOfBirth: Option[Date])
```

And the form..

```
  object MyForm {

     val form = Form(
        mapping(
          "_id" -> ignored(Option.empty[BSONObjectID]),
          "name" -> nonEmptyText,
          "dateOfBirth" -> optional(date)
        )(FormData.apply)(FormData.unapply)
     )

  }
```

And now the critical part. Within the *companion object* of the *case class* (mine is *FormData*) is where to put the following (this was altered from [Stephane Godbillon's answer here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/reactivemongo/date$20in$20form%7Csort:date/reactivemongo/Erdg62C2K_M/FhQZoogQ-j4J)):

```
  implicit val dateRead: Reads[Date] = (__ \ "$date").read[Long].map { date =>
    new Date(date)
  }

  implicit val dateWrite: Writes[Date] = new Writes[Date] {
    def writes(date: Date): JsValue = Json.obj(
      "$date" -> date.getTime
    )
  }
```