# Mapping Json Array to one input box in Scala/MongoDB

Tags: forms, scala, playframework

**Using**

- [Play Framework](https://www.playframework.com),
- [MongoDB](https://docs.mongodb.com/)
- [ReactiveMongo Play JSON library](http://reactivemongo.org/releases/0.12/documentation/json/overview.html)

So in *MongoDB*; imagine that I have a *collection* for a league of teams. Each document represents a team's attributes, e.g.

```
   "_id" : ObjectId("59ea36d3fdc2ce3d73c4be96"),
   "name" : Team 1,
   "stats" : {
      "goalsScoredThisSeason" : 17,
      "goalsConcededThisSeason" : 6,
      "avgTicketPrice" : 74.0,
      "thisSeasonFormArr" : [
          "W",
          "L",
          "D",
          ...
      ]
      ...
```

I'm using [scala forms](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ScalaForms) to create input boxes, fill values from my *collection* (when editing fields), etc. I am able to do so with all of these except for the `JsArray`. There is a feature which creates the right amount of input boxes for the field array ([repeated values](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ScalaForms#repeated-values)) but I would prefer to have all of the values in a single input box, e.g.

> W, L, D, ...

This is my *case class* (using automated mapping):

```
  case class FormData(_id: Option[BSONObjectID], name: String, stats: Option[Stats])

  case class Stats(goalsScoredThisSeason: Int, goalsConcededThisSeason: Int, avgTicketPrice: Double, thisSeasonFormArr: Option[JsArray])
```

So my form looks like this:

```
  object MyForm {

     val form = Form(
        mapping(
          "_id" -> ignored(Option.empty[BSONObjectID]),
          "name" -> nonEmptyText,
          "stats" -> mapping(
             "goalsScoredThisSeason" -> number,
             "goalsConcededThisSeason" -> number,
             "avgTicketPrice" -> of(doubleFormat),
             "thisSeasonFormArr" -> optional(list(text)) // is this correct?
             ...
        )(FormData.apply)(FormData.unapply)
     )

  }
```

Can anyone help as to how I would create the suitable **reads** and **writes** for `thisSeasonFormArr` to ensure that the `jsArray` is converted to a `string` and vice-versa (so that the array can be mapped to one input box separated by commas). Let me know if you need any more details. Many thanks

---

Just to update: I now know that mapping the array (of strings) within the form is done like this `"thisSeasonFormArr" -> optional(list(text))`; ensuring that within the case class we have `thisSeasonFormArr: Option[List[String]]`. This allows to iterate through the `List` in the (*Play*) template to create multiple input boxes as mentioned earlier. So the only issue is to understand what would need to be done to have one input box containing all of the values of the array concatenated (separated by a comma) - being able to map them to the *Scala Play form*; in order to both **read** and **write** the content.

Comment: As far as I can see, there nothing specific to the DB, but about how to define form mapping with JSON. What have you already tried?

Comment: @cchantep - sorry I've just edited my post to show this for the form mapping - `(FormData.apply)(FormData.unapply)`. Is this what you mean? I hope that this is clear what I am trying to achieve - I had a similar issue when mapping to dates in *MongoDB* but I resolved this (as you can [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47481832/format-an-isodate-form-field-in-reactivemongo-play-json))

Comment: @cchantep - also to add I didn't know if the *mapping* for `thisSeasonFormArr` should be `optional(list(text))` or `optional(text)` so this has caused some confusion as to how to format the JSON.

Comment: @cchantep - how about this? Having answered previous questions I've posted; I can see that you know your way around reactiveMongo in Play. I'm just not sure how to ser]elize a JsArr coming in from Mongo

Comment: @cchantep - Looking online; I can see that you know your way around reactiveMongo in Play. I'm just not sure how to convert a JsArr coming in from Mongo into a `List[String]]` and it seems like I've tried everything. Is it `read[JsArray]`? I still can't figure out why it would need anything more than a `implicit val statsFormat: OFormat[Stats] = Json.format[Stats]` with [Play auto mapping](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ScalaJsonAutomated). And is it any different for a *Mongo* collection field with a JsArray of numbers? Lacking documentation on this.